# What is the difference between @user, User i.e. User.new, and user i.e. user.name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between `@user`, `User` i.e. `User.new`, and `user` i.e. `user.name`?

I'm having issues in my app where I have _user.html.erb: `<%= link_to "Edit", [:edit, user] %>` and edit.html.erb: `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>` and it errors out saying `@user is nil`.

I don't understand why the user is not getting passed into the form? And I've come to understand that I don't have a firm grasp of @user, User, etc.

Here is the [full code right here](https://github.com/brunopgalvao/prana/blob/master/app/views/users/_user.html.erb)

Comment: `User` is the actual active record class for the `users` table. `User.new` creates a new instance of a record (e.g., if you want to add a new record to the user table). `@user` is an instance variable for your User controller class which it may have set up to be assigned to an instance of the User active record. `user` looks like a local variable (there's no Rails convention on that other than usual Ruby naming style). If you see `user.name` you'll need to find out what a `user` is. I suppose it's a local variable set to a user record and there's a name field.

Comment: Read a .. tutorial. No, really. The very basic *different* concepts need to be understood, even without RoR involved - instance variables, classes, creating objects, local variables, and methods, etc. See the [Ruby tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) for relevant/useful links that cover these concepts.

Comment: (In this exact case, simply replacing `@user` with `user` ought to "fix the error"; as `user` can't be nil because `user.name` from before doesn't fail .. but that's not really adding to the understanding of the concepts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User  #It is a class

@user  #Instance(or object) of 'User' class.

User.new  # creates new instance(or object) of 'User' class.

user.name  # 'name' is the attribute of 'user' object.
```

Comment: What is the difference between `@user.name` and `user.name`?

Comment: @user.name and user.name both will give you - name of user, the differance is there in '@user' - is a instance variable and 'user' - is a local variable